# Angular pretty URL's not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url-routing, angular-routing

So i've created a SPA angularJS application this was working flawlessly with normal routing e.g. (somesite.com#/something) but then i got tired of the Hash routing and got to know there was something called "pretty url's" with $locationProvider and html5mode.. But as soon as i went for the pretty Url's my content stopped rendering...

My "app.js" file with the routings:

```
/* Configure routes */
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
// Home
        .when("home", {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller : 'mainController'
        })
// Pages
        .when("contact", {
            templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : 'mainController'
        })
        .when("tools", {
            templateUrl: 'partials/tools.html',
            controller : 'mainController'
        })
        .when("saving", {
            templateUrl: 'partials/saving.html',
            controller : 'mainController'
        })
```

My index where i want to render the different pages in the ng-view div:

```
<!-- Website navigation -->
<div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>

<!-- Website content-->
<div ng-view></div>

<!-- Website footer -->
<div ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></div>
```

My Navigation code in "header.html" :

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NavColl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="home">Hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="tools">Verktyg</a></li>
        <li><a href="saving">Sparande</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Love all the help i can get this has been bothering me for a while now, Thank you.

Comment: Did you add a `<base>` tag? [Server-side URL rewriting](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)?

Comment: Yes i added base tag but that did not help..

Answer (score 0):

Please add:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in your `app.config` function.

It doesn't appear in your code.